# Swashbuckle + XmlComments work locally, but fail swagger generation on server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, xml-documentation

I have a webapi project, and I am utilizing the swashbuckle framework to flush out api documentation.

I have followed the directions to build the documentation xml file with my controller and DTO's, and it all works great locally.

However, when generating the swagger document, a 500 error is thrown. I have confirmed if i remove my xml registration line, the swagger doc is generated and returned successfully.

here is my registration line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
                    { 
...
    c.IncludeXmlComments($"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}bin\\Company.MyApp.xml");
...
```

**Update:** I did some additional logging, and while this lne for IncludeXmlComments runs through successfully on startup, when I request the swagger.json file from the server, I am getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Monetary.Scheduling.xml'` exception. when I use the Kudu tools to look into this directory, I cannot find this file.

**TL;DR:** Why is this file showing up fine locally, but when I deploy to Azure using Kudu or a Octopus nugget package, this file is not there?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that somehow the XML file is not making it to your server...
I had this exact issue with an Azure deployment it worked fine in my local machine but not in azure

...and it was because I was missing the XML doc in the release config

[image: Debug]

[image: Release]

Comment: Here is my test project working in Azure: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Comment: If you have time try Swagger-Net that is my fork of swashbuckle but using the latest of swagger-ui

Comment: @HelderSepu I tried above solution but have the same problem when deploying on the Azure portal. any suggestion

Comment: @RizwanShahid create a minimal project on GitHub, paste a link here and I help you troubleshoot it.