# Keep documentation xml file while running publish with -c Release

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, swashbuckle

I'm trying to build a project that includes swashbuckle and for troubleshooting I want to include swagger into a release build.

I've narrowed it down to this now:

When I run

```
dotnet publish -o ./out
```

the xml file ProjectName.xml is generated in the out folder and when I run

```
dotnet publish -o ./out -c Release
```

the xml file is not generated.

The csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DocumentationFile>obj\Debug\ProjectName.xml</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="somefolder\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.4" />
        ...
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        ...
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and I'm pretty certain I *can* narrow it down even a bit further given time but I'm fairly new with dotnet and I also guess someone sees the problem already.

I'm looking for either a way to get this working or an explanation for why this is too wrong to be doable.

PS: Running on linux so no Visual Studio. Otherwise this could have been a possible solution for what I know: [Swashbuckle + XmlComments work locally, but fail swagger generation on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465963/swashbuckle-xmlcomments-work-locally-but-fail-swagger-generation-on-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your csproj file instead of setting `OutputPath` or `DocumentationFile`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add in your .csproj :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>obj\Release\ProjectName.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or remove the condition :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>obj\$(Configuration)\ProjectName.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Removed the condidtion and it worked. Thanks a whole lot! I tried this yesterday but it didn't seem to work then. Possibly I didn't save the file or misread or something. Kind of embarrasing :-]

Comment: A great answer . Thanks guys .

Comment: there's also `GenerateDocumentationFile` (see my answer) which is easier to set and adapts to changes of $(BaseIntermediateOutputPath) ("obj\") and $(IntermediateOutputPath) ("$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\")